# What is the data type of _id in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to create a user Schema using moongose. In user Schema i want to keep the ids of the blogs which written by the user. So what should be the data type of ids.

```
blogIds:{
    type: ???,
    require: true,
}
```

I thought that it can be String but I haven't tried.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans MongoDB uses bson IDs, which usually can be represented as a 24 character hexadecimal string value. In node it's most commonly stored as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get import the type `ObjectId` from mongoose:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';


.
.

blogIds:{
    type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    require: true,
}
```

If not using ES6 `import`, then simply:

`type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]`